# Escape sequence for bold text in Bixolon printer

Tags: c#, bixolon-printer

What is correct syntax for creating Escape Sequences that work with Bixolon printers? I would like to see some samples for bold text that will work on SPP-R200III Bixolon printer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Manual](http://www.bixolon.com/upload/download/manual_spp-r200iii_command_english_rev_1_00.pdf) (page 35), the escape code to toggle bold text is `ESC E` (Hex 1B 45)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of Escape Sequences that can be used with Bixolon printers:

```
//Double-strike mode
printline = "\x1BG1" + printline + "\x1BG0";

// Underline mode 1
printline = "\x1B" + "\x2D" + "\x1" + printline + "\x1B" + "\x2D" + "\x0";

// Underline mode 2
printline = "\x1B" + "\x2D" + "\x2" + printline + "\x1B" + "\x2D" + "\x0";

// Emphasized mode
printline = "\x1B\x21\x8" + printline + "\x1B\x21\x0";
```